# og tag contents are not picking up when i share through fb. using sharethis

Tags: facebook, meta, sharethis

I am trying this in localhost. Here is how I declared og tags . I am using sharethis.js

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="139430409442545"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="ThinkVidya.com">
    <meta property="og:type" content="profile">
    <meta property="profile:first_name" content="kira woka">
    <meta property="profile:last_name" content="K">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost:8080/bangalore/kira-wok-k/735725 ">
    <meta property="og:title" content="kira woka K - Home Tutor in Bangalore for MBBS &amp;    Medical Tuition">
    <meta property="og:description" content="kira woka K provides Home Tuitions in Bangalore for  and MBBS &amp; Medical Tuition. kira woka K profile - My Teaching Philosophy:    
     My approach to teaching reflects the way I was taught by my own professors. The teachers...">

    <meta property="og:image" content="http://localhost:8080/images/photo-placeholder-190x190-Orange-M.jpg">
```

when i share using fb its showing following pop-up

[image]

not even showing full url, you can see this in above screenshot. did i miss anything to include?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

facebook **graph api fetches information from their server side** . the reason why its not picking information is because **your localhost is not accessible from their servers**. you can test open graph tags only after putting your website in a publically accessible url .

you can test open graph data here using [**url debugger from facebook**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) .

Comment: can you tell what the problem was?